# How to predict two targets, the second makes sense only if the first predicted as positive

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on a machine learning problem. The goal is to predict if a client will sign the contract and also how much time will he take to sign.

So this how i project to handle it:
1- train a first model to do classification prediction, to predict positive ones.
2-train second regression model only on training examples for clients who actually signed contracts, and predict time of their response.
3- using first model, predict positive classe
4-using second model, predict the time target, only based on those predicted as positive.

Please can you tell me if my approach is correct, do I introduce any bias? Is there any known methods to handle such problems.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your approach is correct because there is no point in including sign in time for those who did not sign in. In fact if you include them in the regression you cannot even assign any meaningful target value for them. For example if you assign zero as their sign in time it means they were more eager than people who actually signed in which is absurd. If you assign a large value for them your model will put unnecessary emphasis on them and won't perform well.

Comment: Indeed,xashru, I was thinking about your last possibility before posting my question, and I had the same fear about the "Unnecessary emphasis".
thank you for you answer.
That said, I am still interested any Docs or writings about similar situation: I mean Two dependent target, in a way the second has to be predicted afte rthe first.